# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/content/res/TypedArrayUtils.class

Tags: android

[I have shared graddle Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64xgz.png)Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/content/res/TypedArrayUtils.class

Comment: Paste your `build.gradle` file here

Comment: This error occurs when I try to run the project

Comment: i know, It is saying your are importing same time multiple file. That's why i want to see your `build.grade` code.

Comment: Please check the Image of graddle that I have shared with question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error usually occurs when there is duplication of dependencies in gradle file. Check your app gradle file again, search for duplicate dependencies. 
For instance, if google services of version 9.2.0 is added and another google service version for instance say maps is added with version 10.0.0 so here conflict will occur hence resulting with this error

Answer (score 3):

Lİke @Techlnsect mentioned above we need to give direct import, try to remove ++ at the end of compiling element and find suitable for your work

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:2+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

I changed it to and problem gone

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

}