# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry android/support/v4/content/res/TypedArrayUtils.class

Tags: android

I have searched entire stack overflow still unable to resolve this error. These are some links which I have already tried:

[TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/content/res/TypedArrayUtils.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952604/transformexception-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-android-support])

[TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/ExploreByTouchHelper.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234919/transformexception-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-android-support)

[java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240173/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-android-support-v4-app-actionbardra])

[java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult)

[Android project build successfully but ran failed with error: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460383/android-project-build-successfully-but-ran-failed-with-error-java-util-zip-zipe)

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug])

App builds error free.But when I run the application it shows below error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/content/res/TypedArrayUtils.class

There are no duplicate compile gradle lines
There are no duplicate jar files
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please post app build.gradle, this might be a version conflict issue!!

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Post `./gradlew :app:dependencies` tree.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @Gautami Did you solve this ?

Comment: No have not yet